# vertical-align works in opposite way

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/BesP9/) is an example of strange vertical-align behaviour. It works opposite and also I couldn't catch every 'span' element.

The code:

```
#timeline > ul >*:nth-child(even) span, #timeline ul >*:nth-child(even) h1 {
    vertical-align: top
} 

#timeline > ul >*:nth-child(odd) span, #timeline ul >*:nth-child(odd) h1 {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

catches the right element, but that element is formatted in opposite that it should (in my knowledge). The reason of a code was one item up, one down... on a timeline. In pure CSS that's impossible to do that automatically with my html code (cause ther's a nth-**child**() selector not just an nth()). However I'm trying to do that as much in css, then after that add some js.

Comment: 'ul >*' cannot be anything else than 'ul>li' , vertical-align will work on span or h1 display as inline-block i guess, any HTML to show us ?

Comment: You confuse alignment with positioning. Do something like `nth-child(odd) {position:relative; top:3em}` or similar. Your other question is interesting though. Stand by.

Comment: WRT your not catching eveny span: you had `#timeline > ul >*:nth-child(odd)` twice; the bottom one should be `#timeline > ul >*:nth-child(even)`. See [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/BesP9/1/). You will need more CSS there though; the `I` bars there are no longer in the correct position.